# Icinga2 IDo integration with ms-sql

Tags: nagios, icinga

Is there any documentation with integrating icinga2 IDo format with MS-SQL database. Currently I can only find mysql or postgres addons.

I am unfortunately stuck to ms-sql as the only db option so cannot integrate icinga2 with mysql , mariadb or postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following up with the icinga dev team on their mailing list ,I  figured out that icinga2 currently does not support mssql or oracle and does not have any plans on doing so in the near future.

Since the feature is not supported in their "core" , it is not supported by any of the icinga UI's as well